# MySql Select, Replace, INSTR

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which are not directly related:`data` and `locations` with below columns

`locations : id (serial number) name and code`

`data : locCodes` which contains a delimited list of location Codes as **"|loc1|loc2|loc3|"**.

I want to replace the `locCode` in `data` with the `id` from `locations`. I give it a try but can't get it.

This query seems right, but I can't actually get the update piece right.

```
SELECT REPLACE( data.locCodes , CONCAT('|', location.code, '|'), CONCAT('|',     location.id, '|'))
FROM data, location
WHERE INSTR(data.locCodes, CONCAT('|', location.code, '|')) > 0
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02379/3

```
UPDATE data
SET locCodes = (SELECT REPLACE( data.locCodes , CONCAT('|', location.code, '|'), CONCAT('|', location.id, '|'))
FROM data, location
WHERE INSTR(data.locCodes, CONCAT('|', location.code, '|')) > 0);
```

Throws errors about FROM. Very new to MySql, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: what is your desired output. please re write the table with some data

Comment: OP wants to update the whole table to make the `data` table look like `|1|2|` instead of `|locCodeOne|locCodeTwo|`

Comment: Tip : your table structure is not normalized if these tables does not contain heavy data then change the structure of tables.

Comment: @manisha : You want to disply these values on browser Or want to replace  inside the table?

Comment: @diEcho Updated comment. Sorry for the virtual surgery :(

Comment: In response, in order, mavrosxristoforos is correct about desired output. diEcho, I realize it's a bad schema, the denormalization is to address a read only query heavy app. Also, I want to replace inside the table. Trying to learn about how some of the table maintenance might be performed on ongoing basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Manisha, i don't how can i implement the following T-SQL in Mysql.</s>

Give me some time to find a way to do it, (in between u can also try to convert)

**SQL Server**

```
select id,locCodes,
    (
        select '|'+cast(l.id as varchar)
        from location l
        where d.locCodes LIKE '%|'+l.code+'|%'
        for xml path('')
    )
    +'|' as abc
from data d
group by id,locCodes
```

**[MSSQL Answer Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf8b8/1)**

**MySQL**

```
SELECT  data.*,
(
  SELECT concat('|',Replace(GROUP_CONCAT(location.id ),',','|'),'|')
  FROM location
  WHERE find_in_set(location.code, replace(trim(replace(data.locCodes,'|',' ')),' ',','))
) as locCodes1
FROM data
```

**[MySQL Answer Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40975/1)**

Comment: So your fiddle works perfectly in the fiddle, but "as locCodes1" is still a temporary result. How do I actually write that value into the table. Even if it was into a new field: [edited Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/082ad/3)

Comment: Ok. Figured it out after a little more play. Luv's work was key. I just had to unnest the subquery to get it to work with the update. [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0b82/1)